# Azure Service Bus Subscription Client polling interval

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics, azure-servicebus-subscriptions

I have managed to write a small console application to connect to a topic/subscription in the Azure Service Bus. I have sent messages to the subscription and registered a message handler. I see the message handler
polls every 60 seconds. Is there anyway to extend this polling interval to 30 
or 60 minutes for example?

Regards,
Simon

Comment: Did get a good understanding of this? Im looking for documentation on expected response times of client receiving a message once its ended the queue.

Answer (score 0):

I believe both [`Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.servicebus) (.NET Standard) and [`Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging) (.NET Framework) use either AMQP or AMQP over WebSockets under the hood which don't have to poll for messages.

I guess you are checking the network logs and what you are seeing is probably a heartbeat to keep the underlying TCP connection alive.